# Google Tracking Campaign returns just few infos

Tags: android, google-analytics

I'm testing my Google Tracking Campaign before putting my app on the Google Play Store. Following properly the instruction from [HERE](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/testing-play-campaigns), I installed the apk via adb, without starting it, and then I did the instruction

```
adb shell am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER -n <package>/com.google.analytics.tracking.android.CampaignTrackingReceiver --es "referrer" "utm_source=fb&utm_medium=500_600"
```

I just put source and medium since are the only think I do need in my app. (500_600 is a random string). 
Launching the isntruction I get (as expected from the link above)

```
Broadcasting: Intent { act=com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER cmp=<package>/com.google.analytics.tracking.android.CampaignTrackingReceiver (has extras) } Broadcast completed: result=0
```

when I went seeing the logcat I found this:

```
Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Campaign found: utm_source=fb
```

nothing else... Where is medium part? I cant really understand. I do need that info since I need to track those into a db after the app start.  Help me pls! :D

Answer (score 0):

Did things work after you published to the Play Store? I think it might be an encoding or logging issue. I noticed that if I percent-encode the referrer value, the entire thing shows up in logcat. But as long as the correct values are parsed and sent up to GA, everything should be okay.